# I am a beginner in Q. Got multiple questions related to Q

Tags: kdb, q-lang

1. When I type `l: 1 2`, I get back list of `1,2`. But when I type 
   string: `a b`, why I get back `` `assign ``?
2. What does ` sign does in Q? What is its significance?

Comment: "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.**"

Answer (score 1):

> When I type string: a b, why do I get back `assign?

The "assign" error means an "attempt to redefine a reserved word".  See [Runtime Errors](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/error-list/#runtime-errors). For the list of reserved words, see [Reserved Words](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/elements/#reserved-words).

> What does ` sign do in Q?

A back tick ` followed by a series of characters represents a symbol.  For more details, see [Symbols](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/datatypes/#symbols).

Note that q distinguishes between the back tick, ` and the single quote, '.  When prints an error, it uses a single quote. For other uses, see [Case](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#case).